# SQL - records with same date

Tags: sql

I am trying to return records that occur on the same day, but can't figure out how to do this.  Using the script below, I can see there are two perf_no's with the same date, I just don't know how to return only those two items.

```
select perf_no, perf_name, perf_dt
from LVS_TKT_HIST 
where customer_no=1046359
order by perf_dt desc

11038   2014-05-15 20:00:00.000 Patriotic Pops #1
13950   2014-05-15 20:00:00.000 Wine Tier 3
10927   2014-04-25 20:00:00.000 Pops #4 Fri
10833   2014-04-04 20:00:00.000 Evita #4
11269   2014-03-02 19:00:00.000 Lewis & Pizzarelli
```

Comment: Is this on SQL Server?

Comment: Is `2014-05-15` the only day you want or all that have another record on th same day?

Comment: Will you give a Date as an input? Or you want to see which results have the same date more than once?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec8c3/6)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE LVS_TKT_HIST
    ([customer_no] int, [perf_no] int, [perf_dt] datetime, [perf_name] varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO LVS_TKT_HIST
    ([customer_no], [perf_no], [perf_dt], [perf_name])
VALUES
    (1046359, 11038, '2014-05-15 20:00:00', 'Patriotic Pops #1'),
    (1046359, 13950, '2014-05-15 20:00:00', 'Wine Tier 3'),
    (1046359, 10927, '2014-04-25 20:00:00', 'Pops #4 Fri'),
    (1046359, 10833, '2014-04-04 20:00:00', 'Evita #4'),
    (1046359, 11269, '2014-03-02 19:00:00', 'Lewis & Pizzarelli')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT lth.perf_no, lth.perf_name, lth.perf_dt
FROM LVS_TKT_HIST lth
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_no, CAST(perf_dt AS DATE) AS perf_dt
    FROM LVS_TKT_HIST
    GROUP BY customer_no, CAST(perf_dt AS DATE)
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) dt ON dt.customer_no = lth.customer_no AND
        CAST(lth.perf_dt AS DATE) = dt.perf_dt
WHERE lth.customer_no=1046359
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec8c3/6/0)**:

```
| PERF_NO |         PERF_NAME |                    PERF_DT |
|---------|-------------------|----------------------------|
|   11038 | Patriotic Pops #1 | May, 15 2014 20:00:00+0000 |
|   13950 |       Wine Tier 3 | May, 15 2014 20:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: If this help you, you can select it as a correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, this can be done using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the COUNT function with the [OVER clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to partition the rowset by the perf_dt column before the COUNT function is applied.

```
;WITH DATA AS
(
  SELECT perf_no, perf_name, perf_dt, COUNT(*) over (partition BY perf_dt) AS [count]
  FROM LVS_TKT_HIST
  WHERE customer_no=1046359
  GROUP BY perf_no, perf_name, perf_dt
)
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE [count] > 1
```

**Results:**

```
PERF_NO   PERF_NAME          PERF_DT                     COUNT
-------   -----------------  --------------------------  -----
11038     Patriotic Pops #1  May, 15 2014 20:00:00+0000  2
13950     Wine Tier 3         May, 15 2014 20:00:00+0000  2
```

I setup this example on <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0cc9/9)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You could mean many things but I'm going with "Return all records that have other records on the same date in SQL Server"

Like this:

```
  select perf_no, perf_name, perf_dt
   from LVS_TKT_HIST 
   where customer_no=1046359
     AND CAST(perf_dt AS DATE) in 
       (SELECT CAST(perf_dt AS DATE)
        FROM LVS_TKT_HIST 
        WHERE customer_no=1046359
        GROUP BY CAST(perf_dt AS DATE)
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       )
   order by perf_dt desc
```

Comment: I just want to return any instance in which there would be two perf_no's occuring on the same date.  So in the example I initially gave, I only want returned:<br>11038   2014-05-15 20:00:00.000 Patriotic Pops #1<br>
13950   2014-05-15 20:00:00.000 Wine Tier 3

Comment: you could replace having count(*)>1 by having count(*)=2